# How to check if images are being preloaded?

Tags: javascript

I want to preload an image with javascript, the method below seems simple enough but how can I check if the image has preloaded? Thanks 
[Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest modifying the code to add on 'onerror' event handler to the img tags you are generating.  and then handle any failures.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp

Comment: You can do the same for the onload of the img as well: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 1):

Make a log entry in your image's "onload" event.

```
myImage.onload = function(){

   console.log("Image Loaded!");

}
```

If you're not familiar with chrome's developer tools or firefox's Firebug plugin, you should check them out.  They make things like this a breeze.

Also, keep in mind that some browsers require the image.src attribute to be defined after the .onload event.